# Flink with kafka Sink fail to exec: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a exception when i run my code in flink cluster. I thing that the problem is a overlaping .jar files in exec time with maven.

I can run de code in local mode, but when i run de program in kafka client this produce a excetion to try load de "javax/manangent/MBeanServer".

**this is the exception produced by de flink cluster:**

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/flink/runtime/execution/librarycache/FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders$ChildFirstClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.librarycache.FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders$ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders.java:126)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser.unregisterAppInfo(AppInfoParser.java:68)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.close(KafkaProducer.java:1059)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:414)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:288)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.FlinkKafkaProducer.<init>(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:116)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer011.initProducer(FlinkKafkaProducer011.java:960)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer011.beginTransaction(FlinkKafkaProducer011.java:692)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer011.beginTransaction(FlinkKafkaProducer011.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.beginTransactionInternal(TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.java:359)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.initializeState(TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.java:350)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer011.initializeState(FlinkKafkaProducer011.java:867)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:277)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:738)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:289)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**This is my pom.xml file:**

```
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.psa</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink.bridge</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Flink Quickstart Job</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <flink.version>1.6.2</flink.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-streaming-mqtt_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Java Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all necessary dependencies. -->
            <!-- Change the value of <mainClass>...</mainClass> if your program entry point changes. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>

                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-annotations</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop1</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-curator-recipes</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-core</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-java</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-runtime_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-optimizer_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-avro_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-batch_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-streaming_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.10</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-asm</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-netty</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-jackson</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-guava</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.xbean:xbean-asm5-shaded</exclude>

                                    <!-- Also exclude very big transitive dependencies of Flink
                                    WARNING: You have to remove these excludes if your code relies on other
                                    versions of these dependencies.
                                    -->
                                    <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-library</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-compiler</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-reflect</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.typesafe.akka:akka-remote_*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>io.netty:netty-all</exclude>
                                    <exclude>io.netty:netty</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.avro:avro</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-collections:commons-collections</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-compress</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.tukaani:xz</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.objenesis:objenesis</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.twitter:chill_*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.twitter:chill-java</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-lang:commons-lang</exclude>
                                    <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                                    <exclude>joda-time:joda-time</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12</exclude>
                                    <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                                    <!--<exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-math</exclude>-->
                                    <exclude>org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.commons.json</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-codec:commons-codec</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations</exclude>
                                    <exclude>stax:stax-api</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.typesafe:config</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.uncommons.maths:uncommons-maths</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.github.scopt:scopt_*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-io:commons-io</exclude>
                                    <exclude>commons-cli:commons-cli</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>

                                    <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                    Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>

                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.psa.StreamingJob</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <!-- This improves the out-of-the-box experience in Eclipse by resolving some warnings. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>shade</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <!-- This profile helps to make things run out of the box in IntelliJ -->
    <!-- Its adds Flink's core classes to the runtime class path. -->
    <!-- Otherwise they are missing in IntelliJ, because the dependency is 'provided' -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>add-dependencies-for-IDEA</id>

            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>idea.version</name>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
                    <version>${flink.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to update the Scala version suffix of the exclusion of the `maven-shade-plugin`. You are depending on Scala `2.11` dependencies but your are excluding Scala `2.10` dependencies. Changing them to

```
<exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.11</exclude>
<exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-runtime_2.11</exclude>
<exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-optimizer_2.11</exclude>
<exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.11</exclude>
<exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-avro_2.11</exclude>
<exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-batch_2.11</exclude>
<exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-streaming_2.11</exclude>
<exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.11</exclude>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, here i have a first problem. But the problem still occurs.

I fix the problem deleting the **javax/management** from the .jars file, i append the next line in the **<filters>**

Comment: Yes, here i have a first problem. But the problem still occurs.

I fix the problem deleting the **javax/management** from the .jars file, i append the next line in the filters  **<exclude>**javax/management/*</exclude>**